# How to fix " Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entity

I'm just learning spring and I have a problem in the relationship of databases ended with error:

> "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in:
>   Varqina.WebReptile.models.entity.UserEntity.userPropertiesEntity,
>   referenced property unknown:
>   Varqina.WebReptile.models.entity.UserPropertiesEntity.user"

```
UserProperies:
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@Entity
public class UserEntity {
    public enum AccountStatus{
        ACTIVE, PREMIUM, NOT_ACTIVE;
    }
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Integer id;
    private String nickname;
    private String password;
    private @Column(name = "creation_time") LocalDateTime creationTime;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AccountStatus status;
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {})
    private UserPropertiesEntity userPropertiesEntity;

}
UserPropertiesEntity:
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_properties")
public class UserPropertiesEntity {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Integer id;
    private String city;
    private String nation;
    private @Column(name = "birth_day") String birthDay;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserEntity nickname;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mappedBy attribute in the @OneToOne relationship must correspond to the attribute name in the destination Entity.

So it should be "nickname" not "user"

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "nickname",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {})
private UserPropertiesEntity userPropertiesEntity;
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you!